# 'Request' object has no attribute 'method' using fbchat to send a message

Tags: facebook, python-3.x

I'm creating a messaging bot using [fbchat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fbchat/)(version 0.40). I've downloaded all the dependencies ([requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests),[lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.6.4) and [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)) and they're all up to date. however I cannot get even the example to work because of what I believe is an issue involving the requests module.
Can anyone help me and tell me why this error comes up and how to fix it?

Code:

```
import fbchat

client = fbchat.Client(str(EMAIL_ADDRESS),str(PASSWORD))
friends = client.getUsers(str(FRIEND_NAME))
friend = friends[0]
sent = client.send(friend.uid, "Hey")
if sent:
    print("Message sent successfully!")
else:
    print("Message not sent")
```

(I've changed my password and email address to PASSWORD and EMAIL_ADDRESS as well as FRIEND_NAME from my friends name.)

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    chat.send(friend.uid,"Hey")
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 245, in send
    r = self._post(SendURL, data)
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 116, in _post
    return self._session.post(url, headers=self._header, data=payload, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 522, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 459, in request
    hooks = hooks,
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 215, in __init__
    data = [] if data is None else data
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 215, in __init__
    data = [] if data is None else data
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\bdb.py", line 66, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Algie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\Debugger.py", line 21, in user_line
    self.gui.interaction(message, frame)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Plus: I can post my module folders if that would help.

Comment: You need to use the API. Scraping Facebook is not allowed

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't know that